# Nemo action error: sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

Tags: sudo, password, nemo

I got the following bash script to mount a share on my machine:

```
#!/bin/bash
BA_LAST_OCTET=144
BA_IP=$(ip route get 8.8.8.8 | awk 'NR==1 {print $NF}' | awk -F'.' '{print $1,$2,$3"."}' OFS='.')$BA_LAST_OCTET
PROMPT="Sudo password: "

CAN_I_RUN_SUDO=$(sudo -n uptime 2>&1|grep "load"|wc -l)
if [ ${CAN_I_RUN_SUDO} -le 0 ]
then
    . getpass.sh $1 

    echo $PASSWORD | sudo -S : >/dev/null 2>&1
fi
OUTPUT=$(sudo mount.cifs //$BA_IP/huginn/ /mnt/huginn/ -o username=fileshare,password="",rw,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 2>&1)
if [ -z "$OUTPUT" ]; then
    HUGINN="Huginn... Mounted."
else

    HUGINN="Huginn... Error.\n"$OUTPUT
fi
OUTPUT=$(sudo mount.cifs //$BA_IP/muninn/  /mnt/muninn/ -o username=fileshare,password="",rw,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 2>&1)
if [ -z "$OUTPUT" ]; then
    MUNINN="Muninn... Mounted."
else

    MUNINN="Muninn... Error.\n"$OUTPUT
fi
MSG=$HUGINN"\n"$MUNINN"\nFinalized."
if [[ $1 == "--gui" ]] ; then
    zenity --info --title="Blackarmor" --text="$MSG"  2>/dev/null
else
    echo -e  "Mounting  Blackarmor shares... \n\n"$MSG
fi
```

It works perfectly well from command line. But if I try to use it in a Nemo Action it shows the following message:

```
Huginn... Error.
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
Muninn... Error.
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
Finalized.
```

`. getpass.sh` just gets a password from gui or command line and put it in PASSWORD var. It's working ok, even in Nemo Action (I tested it).

The Nemo Action looks like this:

```
[Nemo Action]
Active=true
Name=Mount Blackarmor share
Exec=/bin/bash /usr/bin/ba --gui
Selection=Any
Extensions=any;
```

Anyone know how I can fix this ?

I also accept recommendations on how to run this in a better way. The same problem happens if I try to create a launcher pointing to this script on the Desktop without checking "Launch in terminal" option.

**Edit**

as @meuh suggested, I tried to change this:

```
. getpass.sh $1 

echo $PASSWORD | sudo -S : >/dev/null 2>&1
```

to this:

```
 #. getpass.sh $1

 SUDO_ASKPASS=/usr/bin/ssh-askpass sudo -A : >/dev/null 2>&1
```

but it showed the exact same message. ssh-askpass is the Ubuntu/Mint version of x11-ssh-askpass (I use Mint).
Just to remember, it works in a laucher if I check "Launch in terminal". But I really don't like the big window that appears behind and it also doesn't work as a Nemo Action which would be preferable.

Comment: This is a generic error typically from executing a command as sudo, but the runtime user is not in the sudoers file. Have you verified the runtime user is allowed to execute these commands as sudo in the sudoers file?

Comment: The runtime user is my account. I'm obviously allowed to execute sudo in my computer as my account is an administrative account. Or are launchers and Nemo Actions runned by another user ? AFAIK the user running these processes is my user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing your own password-getting command you can ask `sudo` to run an existing one, such as `x11-ssh-askpass` which on my Fedora system is in a package of the same name. You would say

```
SUDO_ASKPASS=/usr/libexec/openssh/x11-ssh-askpass sudo -A somecommand
```

and it will popup a gui for you to enter a password.

Alternatively, you can be less secure and allow `sudo` to run a command when there is no tty by editing the sudoers file with `sudo visudo /etc/sudoers` (be careful: keep a root login somewhere to rescue you if needed) and adding a line:

```
Defaults:myname !requiretty
```

for your username *myname*.

---

If you need a tty you can use a program like `script` to provide one whilst running the command, eg:

```
script <<<'SUDO_ASKPASS=/... sudo -A mycommand'
```

You would probably need to surround your entire script with `script`, or you would get a new tty each time, and `sudo` would ask you for a password each time.

Comment: See my edit. :)

Comment: Perhaps you can use `script` to provide a tty cheaply. See my addition.

Comment: Perfect. Now it worked fine. Even the Nemo Actions. Thanks.  :)